# Getting error "Cannot read property 'parent' of undefined" when try to remove child

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I have function and I want this function remove child when child added to "History"child.
I am getting error below,when I add child to "History"child.

> Error:
>   [image]
>
> ---

Here is my function code :

```
  exports.onHistoryAdded = functions.database.ref('/Users/Customers/{pushId}/History/{pushID}')
  .onWrite((snapshot, context) => {
  var pushId=snapshot.key;

    return snapshot.ref.parent.child(pushId).remove();
});
```

---

[image]

Comment: Please include the error and database structure as text instead of an image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code doesn't seem to have been correctly updated from the beta version of Firebase Functions to the 1.0 release.

In the latest release, the first argument to `onWrite` is a [`change`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/functions.Change) and not a `snapshot`. You can get the latest snapshot from `change.after`. So:

```
exports.onHistoryAdded = functions.database.ref('/Users/Customers/{pushId}/History/{pushID}')
  .onWrite((change, context) => {
    var snapshot = change.after;

    var pushId=snapshot.key;

    return snapshot.ref.parent.child(pushId).remove();
});
```